# Inject a service with metadata by Ninject

Tags: ninject

I'm trying to inject the services with its metadata, so I can pick the services I want at runtime by the metadata, just like the Relationship Types [`Meta<T>`](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/metadata.html) of Autofac.

I can easiliy get all bindings by calling `IKernel.GetBindings(Type)`, but there is no way to instantiate an instance from the the `IBinding`.

How could I implement this scene ?